# Why my C program is not working for Grading points?

Tags: c, floating-point, precision, integer-division, integer-arithmetic

I have written a C program to find 5 students grade point. I shows correct result if a student failed but when all student pass it is not showing any answer. Please help me to solve it.
Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int mark[5], failed = 0, sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) scanf("%d", &mark[i]);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        sum = sum + mark[i];
        if (mark[i] < 40) failed++;
    }
    double marks = (double)((sum / 500) * 100);
    if (failed > 0) printf("Ops! Failed\n");
    else
    {
        if (marks >= 90) printf("%d%%: Grade A", marks);
        else if (marks >= 80 && marks <= 89) printf("%.2lf%%: Grade B\n", marks);
        else if (marks >= 70 && marks <= 79) printf("%.2lf%%: Grade C\n", marks);
        else if (marks >= 60 && marks <= 69) printf("%.2lf%%: Grade C\n", marks);
        else if (marks >= 40 && marks <= 59) printf("%.2lf%%: Grade D\n", marks);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Wrong output image: [image]

Comment: `printf("%d%%: Grade A", marks);` --> `printf("%.0f%%: Grade A", marks);`

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Post text as text.

Comment: You are doing integer division, chnage `(double)((sum / 500) * 100);` to `(((double)sum / 500) * 100);`

Comment: Please, why have you changed the code? Rolled back to the question as asked.

Comment: Thanks sir Weather Vane. It works. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following code I have also changed the upper bounds (otherwise you don't display anything if `marks=79.8` for example):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int mark[5], failed = 0, sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) scanf("%d", &mark[i]);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        sum = sum + mark[i];
        if (mark[i] < 40) failed++;
    }
    double marks = (((double)sum / 500) * 100);
    printf("marks=%f\n", marks);
    if (failed > 0) printf("Ops! Failed\n");
    else
    {
        if (marks >= 90) printf("%.2f%%: Grade A\n", marks);
        else if (marks >= 80 && marks < 90) printf("%.2f%% Grade B\n", marks);
        else if (marks >= 70 && marks < 80) printf("%.2f%% Grade C\n", marks);
        else if (marks >= 60 && marks < 70) printf("%.2f%% Grade C\n", marks);
        else if (marks >= 40 && marks < 60) printf("%.2f%% Grade D\n", marks);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note:  Could simply leave the upper bound off  `(marks >= 70 && marks < 80)` --> `(marks >= 70)`.

Answer (score 2):

Your program has two main syntactical issues:

#### 1.

```
double marks = (double)((sum / 500) * 100);
```

`(sum / 500)` uses integer arithmetic. The fraction part is truncated towards zero. The explicit cast to `double` just converts the result value of the whole arithmetic expression to a `double`.

Either use

```
double marks = ((double) sum / 500) * 100);
```

or

just specify the variable `sum` of type `double`.  With that you can also omit the cast to `double` at the initialization of `marks`.

```
double sum;
....

double marks = ((sum / 500) * 100);
```

---

#### 2.

```
if (marks >= 90) printf("%d%%: Grade A", marks);
```

You use the `%d` conversion specifier to print a `double` value of `marks`, which invokes [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior).

Use `%f`, or, if you want to stick to convention/consensus, `%.2lf` like you did at all other `printf()`s.

Note: For `printf()` you can use the `%f` conversion specifier to print a `double` value, not necessary `%lf` like it is required at `scanf()` to consume a `double`.

---

Side note:

- To be standard-compliant, change `int main()` to `int main(void)`.